# Reading XLSX file in Groovy

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I'm using groovy code to read XLSX file

```
systemChartsData = readFile file: "SystemCharts.xlsx"
systemChartsData = systemChartsData.toString()
for(line in (systemChartsData)){
    println (line)
}
```

I'm not getting the content as it is. The output shows unclear characters.
Is there anyway to read a XLSX file?

Comment: Check out the [readCSV](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readcsv-read-content-from-a-csv-file-in-the-workspace) function. It can be used with the `excelFormat` to read excel files: `def records = readCSV file: 'input.csv', format: excelFormat`. output is returned as a list of A List of [CSVRecord](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html).

Comment: @NoamHelmer Thanks for your answer, but unfortunetly I tried it but my Jenkins couldn't identified readCSV function

Comment: You will need to install the [Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/).

Comment: @NoamHelmer it appears that this tool didn't help, it provides wayvtoread csv not xlsx files :|